# Prove or disprove: if the limit of $a_{n}$ goes to $\infty$, then $a_{n}$ has a minimum number.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove or disprove: if the limit of $a_{n}$ goes to $\infty$, then $a_{n}$ has a minimum number.

Well I know from the definition of a series that goes to $\infty$ that there is a number $K>0$ that from a certain place $a_{n}>K$.But is $K$ the minimum here or is there other numbers smaller than it?

Comment: I think you need to state your question more clearly. You should also use Latex when writing on this forum.

Comment: There is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $a_n\gt a_1$. It follows that the smallest of $a_1,\dots,a_N$ is the smallest value of the $a_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has a minimum number, if $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ then as you said for any $K > 0$ there is an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ implies $a_n > K$. Then the minimum is  $\min \{a_1, \dots, a_N\}$